# Problems with w3 total cache

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I installed the plugin W3 total cache but It crashed an important plugin, so I have to delete it. The roblem is that my site is still running a cache version.

I follow the instruction for delete the plugin: unchecked all options, disable and delete the plugin. I look up for the folders: cache and w3cache and proceed to delete it.

I check the .htaccess and is ok. But still the cache version is loading.

The web is: https://noia.pe/

Comment: Maybe your browser cache is loading. Clear the browser cache or just load your site in incognito mode.

Comment: I clear the cache after all the steps.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve the problem. I don't know why W3 Total Cache create problems with the jquerys. This was the error on some parts of the web:

Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

So I fix it adding this: jQuery(function($)...) instead of function() and now is ok.

I don't know why this happened, all the other pages are working ok, and as I said the only thing that was diferent with this was that plugin.